# gcc -Wpadded is inconsistant

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'd like to know when the size of a struct does not equal the combined size of it's members, in other words, when it is padded. gcc has a warning option to do exactly that, `-Wpadded`.

From https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html: "Warn if padding is included in a structure, either to align an element of the structure or to align the whole structure."

Using this option didn't seem to catch padding where it should've though, so I wrote a simple test to demonstrate my issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

struct test {
    uint16_t a;
    uint8_t b;
} test;

int main() {
    cout << sizeof(test) << ", " << alignof(test) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

compiling this with `g++ test.cpp -Wpadded` outputs `warning: padding struct size to alignment boundary`, and running the executable gives `4, 2`, exactly as I'd expect. Changing the struct to

```
struct test {
    uint8_t b;
    uint16_t a;
} test;
```

and running the resulting executable gives `4, 2`, but no warning is given.

Both structs have the same size and alignment, the size of `uint8_t` is obviously 1 byte, and `uint16_t` 2, so shouldn't I be getting a warning here? A page talking about various gcc options (https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/best-and-worst-gcc-clang-compiler-flags) has a test similar to this one, and according to them, a warning is output in both situations.

I also ported the code to C (without the prints)

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct test {
    uint8_t b;
    uint16_t a;
} test;

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

And got the same result.

I'm using gcc 8.1.0 from MinGW-W64.

Comment: I see warnings for both: https://godbolt.org/z/P1YxKaGGd

Comment: Works as expected here: https://godbolt.org/z/cGd1sKGEb Maybe just a MinGW thing

Comment: @RetiredNinja That's odd, it's possible it is just MinGW, but searching 'mingw-w64 "Wpadding"' doesn't come up with anything, I feel like surely someone else would've noticed.

Comment: Reinstalling MinGW didn't help, neither did porting the code to C.

Comment: Could you paste the exact test program with missing warning, and the command you're using to compile it?

Comment: @aschepler The given code is the exact program. Command is `g++ test.cpp -Wpadded` or `gcc ...` on my C port. The C port just takes out the printing, changes <cstdint> to <stdint>, and takes out anything to do with std.

Comment: Forgive the suspicion of user error, but describing the edits made will leave out details the author is blind to, but an actual cut and paste won't.

Comment: @aschepler I added the C code to the question.

Comment: Yes, still gives me the warning. Strange.

Comment: Try it with [-mno-ms-bitfields](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mms-bitfields).

Comment: Can be reproduced on linux with [-mms-bitfields](https://godbolt.org/z/GGzc37vjq).

Comment: @ssbssa Interesting! Compiling with `-mno-ms-bitfields` does successfully give both warnings. I'll have to read the docs for the option a bit more, but that's something.

Comment: With the above option, I also managed to find a question from ~9 years ago (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283164/a-bug-in-gcc-implementation-of-bit-fields) that has a similar problem, with a solution being to use the option. It seems msvc's packing behavior is a bit odd, and for compatibility on windows targets, gcc uses msvc's behavior by default.

Comment: But according to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#index-mms-bitfields), this option should only make a difference for either `packed` structures, or structures containing bit-fields. So I do think this is a bug with `-Wpadded`, since this example doesn't contain any of them.

Comment: @ssbssa I found that odd as well, especially as the C++ example printed the same sizes/alignments for both structs, so you're probably right about it being a problem with the warning.

Comment: I think the changes for [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52238) are responsible, since it added a check for `!targetm.ms_bitfield_layout_p (rli->t)` to this variant of the `-Wpadding` option.

Comment: @ssbssa That seems likely, as the bug was reported for 4.2. Using https://godbolt.org/, I can replicate the issue in all gcc versions 10.3-4.4, but not 4.1. I'll try and open a bug report on the gcc bugzilla.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is in the comments, but for someone who will just seek answer in "big post":

As [@ssbssa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983398/ssbssa) suggested:

> Try it with -mno-ms-bitfields.

It will work when compiling with both `-Wpadded` and `-mno-ms-bitfields` flags active.

Comment: Note that although this *will* cause padding to be correctly reported, `-mno-ms-bitfields` may change the way bitfields are packed, which could change the behavior of a program. This is almost certainly a bug in GCC, which has been reported at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=100058.