# Is bool safe in a bitfield definition?

Tags: c++, boolean, bit-fields

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ bitfield packing with bools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308364/c-bitfield-packing-with-bools)

Is it guaranteed to be safe to use C++'s `bool` keyword inside a bitfield definition?

Something like:

```
struct flags {
    bool a : 1;
    bool b : 1;
}
```

Comment: Some answers here: [C++ bitfield packing with bools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308364/c-bitfield-packing-with-bools) may help you.  Why do you want to do it in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  In practice, you can use `sizeof(bool) * CHAR_BIT` as your guide to knowing how many bits are available.

[From C++98](http://www-d0.fnal.gov/~dladams/cxx_standard.pdf), § 9.6.3

> A bit-field shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1).

From C++98, § 3.9.1.7

> Types bool, char, wchar_t, and the signed and unsigned integer types are collectively called integral
>   types

Answer (score 8):

From C++03 9.6 "Bit-fields":

> A bit-field shall have integral or enumeration type (3.9.1).  It is
>   implementation-defined whether a plain (neither explicitly signed nor
>   unsigned) char, short, int or long bit-field is signed or unsigned.  A
>   bool value can successfully be stored in a bit-field of any nonzero
>   size. ...
>
> If the value true or false is stored into a bit-field of type bool of
>   any size (including a one bit bit-field), the original bool value and
>   the value of the bit-field shall compare equal. ...

3.9.1/7 "Fundamental types" specifies that `bool` is an integral type.